# Python - Opening all .txt on a folder and checking lines for a matching variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a keys1.txt, keys2.txt, keys3.txt and keys4.txt
And my program takes an input of like `ABC123`

I'll have to make by program check keys1.txt for a line that has that input. If it doesn't have it, it goes to keys2.txt, etc.

The file must retrieve the names of the txt files, the names can't be something hardcoded on the source.
I'm aware of how to do this if I hardcode the file names but that can't be done in this case.

Currently I have it checking the file names and getting them on a list and opening all of them. I do be having problems with checking if my key belongs to any, and, if it does, getting to know to which of the files it belongs.

```
file_list = next(os.walk("Keys"))[2]
    print(file_list)
    for filename in file_list:
        with open("Keys" + filename) as f_obj:
            f_obj
```

All of the files would look like

QWE123

ASY981

ASD192

...

Comment: Please be aware [so] is not a code-writing service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi added some more text and got what I currently have to the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you need to open those files but you can't hardcode them into the program, you will probably have to ingest them as command line arguments. Then you can execute your program like this:

```
$ python code.py ABC123 keys1.txt keys2.txt keys3.txt
```

where you search for `ABC123` in the files provided in the command line. You can read more about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each .txt file and line in that file (You haven't specified what these txt files look like). Check for a match with the various methods, I would need more details and what you have tried so far to help further than that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `os.listdir` to get a list of the files that you'll then iterate through.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

```
files_list = os.listdir('/path/to/keys')  # ['keys1.txt', ...]
search_string = 'ABC1234'
found = False

for file in files_list:
    if found:
        break
    with open(file, 'r') as fo:
        for line in fo:
            if line == search_string:
                found = file
                break

print(f'Found line `{search_string}` in file `{found}`.}
```